# bash: getting integer expression expected

Tags: bash, scripting

Here is the piece of code that gives the problem:

```
if [ " ls -l ~/sysbackups | wc -l " -gt 5]
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use :

```
if [ `ls -l  ~/sysbackups | wc -l` -gt 5 ];then
    echo XXXXX
fi;
```